# Python3: How to extract each field in a dataframe of ASCII names?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, label

I have a csv file with a column of Chemical names:

```
"ligands"   <-label
"CaffeicAcid"
"Cannflavin-A"
"Cannflavin-B"
"Cannflavin-C"
"Diosmetin"
"Echinacoside"
"Hesperetin"
"L-CichoricAcid"
```

my python script is:

```py
import pandas as pd

ligands = pd.read_csv('Ligand_Ce.list.csv')
print(ligands)
```

Gives me:

```
current_namespace=True)
          ligands
0     CaffeicAcid
1    Cannflavin-A
2    Cannflavin-B
3    Cannflavin-C
4       Diosmetin
5    Echinacoside
6      Hesperetin
7  L-CichoricAcid
```

How can I iteratively each field for use as a label my script?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by *label*? Do you want to convert the dataframe to dictionary?

Comment: The 'label' is the name of the chemical that goes in

with open("Ligand.list") as ligands_f:
    for line in ligands_f:
        ligand = line.strip()
        print("name of Ligand = :",ligand)
        for num in range(1,11):
            name_in = "{}.{}.log".format(ligand,num)
            data = np.genfromtxt(name_in,skip_header=28, skip_footer=1)
            name_s = ligand+'-BE'
            f = open(name_s, 'a')
            f.write(str(data[1,1])+'\n')
            f.close()

later in the script.